# Spring/Hibernate Truncate/Delete all rows from a table - Transaction issues

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, transactions

I have a Camel project and after we create a controll bean we want to clean up a DB log table. SO each time we run the application we TRUNCATE a table called agent orders. This is setup in an Enity object as a named query.

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name="cleanOrderTable", query="TRUNCATE agent_orders",resultClass= AgentOrderEntity.class)
```

The code that calls this query looks like:

```
@Component("mgr")
public class Controller{ 

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="camel")
    private EntityManager em;
    .......
    @Transactional
    public void clearHistoricalOrders() throws Exception{
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("cleanOrderTable");
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

Call the clear history method we get an error `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query`

I have tried everything, `UserTransaction`, `em.getTransaction().begin` - nothing works. Any idea how I can run this query?

We have the following tran manager setup in our app context.xml:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emFactory" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try debugging and check whether your controller is proxied and whether there's transaction-related code executed before your method. Try enabling database server logs to check what queries really get executed.
- Make sure you don't have any ServletFilters that set-up a read-only transaction prior to getting to your Controller.
- Make sure your entity manager is the one that's passed to the transaction manager.
- Also, I've found some info advising against using @PersistenceContext in servlets: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ss141213/archive/2005/12/dont_use_persis.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'd try executing the query with a `TransactionTemplate` just to check that the @Transactional annotation really isn't having an effect.

Also, what's up with `resultClass= AgentOrderEntity.class`? Why does a query that truncates a table need to return something?